# Cannot resolve store in container (React, Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

in the beginning, I want to sign that I am amateur in JS and React. I am facing a problem that my container that is shown using `React-Router` is not receiving store. I do not know what the problem is. I have wrapped root component with `Provider` and my application shows such error all the time:
[image]

Here is a snippet of my `Application component`:

```js
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    adress: require('./StudiosListRedux').reducer
})

const store = createStore(rootReducer)

const App = ({store}) => (
  <Provider store={store} >
    <BrowserRouter history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={WelcomeScreen} />
        <Route path='/main' component={StudiosList} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
)
```

and here is my `WelcomeScreen container`:

```js
export class WelcomeScreen extends Component {
    state = {
        city: '',
        street: '',
        number: '',
        withDrive: false
    }

    handleCityChange = (text) => {
        console.log('city', text)
        this.setState({
            city: text
        })
    }

    handleStreetChange = (text) => {
        console.log('street', text)
        this.setState({
            street: text
        })
    }

    handleNumberChange = (text) => {
        console.log('number', text)
        this.setState({
            number: text
        })
    }

    handleCheckBoxClick = () => {
        console.log('checkbox', 'pushed')
        this.setState({
            withDrive: !this.state.withDrive
        })
    }

    handleSearchClick = () => {
        const { city, street, number, withDrive } = this.state
        this.props.fetchStudios('query')
    }

    render () {
        const { city, street, number, withDrive } = this.state
        return (
            <Container>
                <SearchComponent
                    withDrive={withDrive}
                    streetValue={street}
                    cityValue={city}
                    numberValue={number}
                    onStreetChange={this.handleStreetChange}
                    onCityChange={this.handleCityChange}
                    onNumberChange={this.handleNumberChange}
                    onCheckBoxClick={this.handleCheckBoxClick}
                    onSubmitClick={this.handleSearchClick}
                />
            </Container>
        )
    }
}

export const mapStateToProps = state => {
    destination: state.adders.toJS()
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    fetchStudios: StudiosActions.studiosRequest
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WelcomeScreen)
```

Can anyone help me with my problem? What should I do to provide store to my container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ReactDOM.render(<App store={store} />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

You forgot to pass store to app, it seems . I might be wrong, there can be other reasons apart from this,

Comment: I am passing it -> I have updated my question so you can see how I create it

Comment: You are not passing it to the App . store value gets updated to undefined in the APP  component. import store where you are doing reactdom.render same way i have answered

Comment: Ok, you might be right. I will check it as soon as I will have access to computer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If `App` is your root component it has no `props`, here you are trying to access an `undefined` `store` prop and you're overriding the `const` declaration you made before.

Just remove the `{ store }` prop declaration :

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer)

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store} >
    <BrowserRouter history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={WelcomeScreen} />
        <Route path='/main' component={StudiosList} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
)
```